# Nested Key word Loops structure Questions

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

***(What my program Does)***

----------[Code worksheet for program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye9dw.png)

Want to ***fill*** each cell in **column B** with the associative Assigned To Name in **column E**  (previously populated with raw data) when the Statements text in **Column A** contains a color found in the Keyword **Column D**

Program runs by executing *Nested Loops* which uses the **Instr** function. The structure I've designed creates a mechanized matching process. Prorgram searches for keywords with **INSTR** function: used in the the **parent string** (mytext)variable is the string inside which the ‘substring’ is to be searched ("blue").

If InStr(MyText, "Blue") And Cells(y, 4) = "Blue" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If (("**Mytext**" 'primary_string') variable in Column A (Statements) contains text that matches with the substring , "blue", 'substring')

**AND**  Cells (y, 4) ="Blue"

*if these conditions above are met the code then executes upon the THEN statement*

**THEN**

---

---

**My program Questions**

My questions are focused on best understanding the mechanics of designing this code. I have put together programs where sometimes I'm more lucky in the end result & want to improve knowledge.

**Loop naming structure**- Understanding my program uses a nested loop (where one loop executes inside another loop)

**1**. Am I correct to say Dowhile (x,1)'col A satements' is the outerloop ?

**2.**   Am I correct to say Do While (y,4) 'Col D keyword' is the innerloop?

**3.** Is it correct to say myText 'primary string' is searching for the text stated in the 'substring' "Blue")?

If InStr(MyText, "Blue") And Cells(y, 4) = "Blue" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

Looping structure questions (per my assumptions)

**4.**   Does Y = y+ 1 (inner loop) come before x = x + 1 (outer loop) so it exits inner loop (Col D keyword) to check keyword phrases in Col A statements)?

**5.**Why is it necessary to use the keyword Loop after y= y+1 (is that initiating the loop)?

**6.** Why is it necessary to write Y+2 after x=x+1 / is this the proper methodology to counter the next iteration of the loop? I ask since we already have Y=Y+1 ...

**7.** why don't we have to write x=2

y = y + 1
Loop
x = x + 1
y = 2
Loop

---

**Code Structure** & **Variables**

---

**Column A** - Statements (pre populated)

**Column B**- Assigned To (initially blank column)

**Column C** - blank column

**Column D**- Keyword (contains color text keyword)

**Column E**- Assigned To (name that fills Column B -if text contained in Column A matches with Column D

---

**(Code in My Program)**

---

```
Sub search_color()

x = 2
y = 2

Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""

MyText = Cells(x, 1)

Do While Cells(y, 4) <> ""

If InStr(MyText, "Blue") And Cells(y, 4) = "Blue" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Brown") And Cells(y, 4) = "Brown" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Orange") And Cells(y, 4) = "Orange" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Yellow") And Cells(y, 4) = "Yellow" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Pink") And Cells(y, 4) = "Pink" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "White") And Cells(y, 4) = "White" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Red") And Cells(y, 4) = "Red" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Purple") And Cells(y, 4) = "Purple" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

If InStr(MyText, "Black") And Cells(y, 4) = "Black" Then Cells(x, 2) = Cells(y, 5)

y = y + 1

Loop

x = x + 1

y = 2

Loop

End Sub
```

---

Comment: First, try to indent the code, so it will be easier to read. Regarding your questions: 1 - you are right. 2 - you are right. 3 - are you looking for the exact word, or if it is a part of a bigger string in `MyText`. 4 - you are right. 5 - Every `Do While` loop in the beginning calls for `Loop` to close it at the end. 6 - you want to reset to inner loop. 7 - you use `x = x + 1` because you want to advance the outer loop by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub search_color()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = 2

    Do While Cells(x, 1)  ""
        y = 2

        Do While Cells(y, 4)  ""

            If InStr(1, Cells(x, 1).Text, Cells(y, 4).Text, vbTextCompare) Then
                Cells(y, 5) = Cells(x, 2)
                Exit Do
            End If

            y = y + 1

        Loop

        x = x + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```